# Escape quotes inside su -c

Tags: linux, shell, escaping, quote, su

I would like to pass a path potentially containing whitespace into an `su -c` command inside a `.sh` script:

```
su -c "xdg-desktop-menu install ${DesktopFile}" -m "${Username}"
```

$DesktopFile is my path that needs to get escaped. I tried many variations with `'` inside `""`, with `\"` and several braces, but I have not come up with a solution. Interestingly enough, xdg-desktop-icon works fine, but xdg-desktop-menu dies at the whitespace. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, `printf '%q'` can be used to escape special characters when quoting is insufficient.

```
su -c "xdg-desktop-menu install $(printf '%q' "$DesktopFile") -m $(printf '%q' "$Username")"
```

Notice that `$(printf...)` doesn't need quotes, but `"$DesktopFile"` does. The variable needs to be passed to `printf` safely, so it has to be quoted. `printf '%q'`'s output is guaranteed to be immune to word splitting and globbing, so it doesn't need quotes. (Although, if you wanted to quote it, you could. It would need `\"` on either side.)

Comment: thanks. 2 issues: a) i wanted to use sh instead of bash, so no %q available, and b) -m is an option for su, not xdg-desktop-menu, so the quotes will change a bit. b) i can solve, but a) is a problem... any suggestions for printf %q on sh?

Comment: ok, switched to /bin/bash for testing and found this:
`FFQ=$(printf '%q' "$DesktopFile")`
`su -c "xdg-desktop-menu install $FFQ" -m "$Username"`
still splits after the white space.

Comment: found a(n older) bug report for xdg-desktop-menu and white spaces, even when passed correctly escaped. maybe my version still has this bug.

Answer (score 0):

i can't make out if this is a bug in xdg-desktop-menu, since it works in xdg-desktop-icon, nevertheless there is a workaround I am now using:

```
cd "$PathWithSpaces"
su -c "xdg-desktop-menu install $DesktopFilenameWithoutSpaces" -m "$Username"
```

`PathWithSpaces` contains `DesktopFilenameWithoutSpaces`, seems to work reliably.